# Dynamic log files based on domain content?

Tags: java, log4j

Using Log4j, is there a way to have entries logged to different files based on domain content?

For example, suppose I wanted all the logging information for a particular loan number, or a customer name, or a company identifier, logged together in a dynamically generated log file, called something like loan1234.log, customerJimPhelps.log, or companyAcmeCorp.log.  The specific log files needed would not be known before hand (can't predict which loans or customers will need logging before hand).  This would be for support and debug purposes in a production environment.

Comment: I haven't heard of an existing Appender with different filenames based on a domain. But you could write your own appender based on the class org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton and create normal fileappenders based on the message. e.g. message is 'domain:companyAcme <text to log>'. 'domain:companyAcme' could be parsed from the message and you could create a FileAppender based on the domain name.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own appender like below:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout;
import org.apache.log4j.FileAppender;

public class Foo {
   static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Foo.class);
   public static void main(String args[]) {

      // setting up a FileAppender dynamically...
      SimpleLayout layout = new SimpleLayout();    
      FileAppender appender = new FileAppender(layout,"WhateverYouLike.log",false);    
      logger.addAppender(appender);

      logger.info("WhateverElseYouLike");

      logger.removeAppender(appender);

   }
}
```